# Shopify defining schema

Tags: schema, shopify, footer

I erroneously deleted the ‘footer.liquid’ file in the Providence theme.

I am unable unable to create a new footer.liquid file in sections as I am getting the error below:

“New schema is incompatible with the current setting value. Invalid type value for block '1523601164583'. Type must be defined in schema. New schema is incompatible with the current setting value. Invalid type value for block '1523858388687'. Type must be defined in schema.New schema is incompatible with the current setting value. Invalid type value for block '1523592394611'. Type must be defined in schema.New schema is incompatible with the current setting value. Invalid type value for block '1523858779593'. Type must be defined in schema”

Any ideas?

Comment: Shopify does not allow for roll back, the best you can do is create another providence theme and copy and paste that blank footer into a new footer.liquid file. If it is not letting you create it make a download a duplicate of the theme then re-upload it but manually add the footer file into the zip prior to re-uploading.

Comment: Sweet thanks, I like uploading the files in a .zip to get around the lack of FTP

Answer (score 2):

I know its been a while but in case anyone ends up on this thread looking for the same thing or the poster of the question did not find a fix (probably not the case) up to this point, I will attempt to answer with how I got around this.

First of all lets examine why this happens, from my understanding, each time we add or modify certain values inside a section schema, the **settings_data.json** located in the **config** folder, will have settings generated inside of it upon usage of that section.
So when we go back into the section and change for example the **type** of a **block**, it will no longer match the existing settings inside of the **settings_data.json** and as such you will get an error back.

So how do if fix it? We simply go into the Shopify Store Adimin and remove the blocks that make use of the type we've changed, after we do this we can easily define any new type we want, add the blocks back and we will no longer receive an error.